# Getting StackOverFlow error while calling WCF metadata in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller

I am getting below error while calling WCF service.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

[StackOverflowException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) are often caused by an infinite loop or infinite recursion. Check if there is such a situation in your code.